Why does NodeMCU keeps resetting?
I have connected my NodeMCU V3 to my laptop via Micro-USB (Good Quality).
If I enter a basic code, e.g. LED blinking or Sensor reading, it works fine.
But when I tried to connect to WiFi, NodeMCU keeps reconnecting to my PC constantly, checked it through the device manager.
When I open the Serial Monitor, it either shows those square blocks, the ones we see when we enter incorrect Baud Rate or It wont open Serial Monitor because device is not connected.
Now I have to hold the reset button so that I can upload the previous code.
This is the code I am using to connect to WiFi.
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "WiFiSSID";
const char* password = "WiFiPassword";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(100);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
    // Your main code goes here
}

The two main reasons for this to happen are faulty cables and Broken MCU, but that is not the case. It works normally when we don't want to use WiFi.
I also read it could be WDT (WatchDog Timmer) but I am not sure.
Why wont the ESP stay stable after providing the WiFi library?

try to clear the flash memory with esptool to clear the WiFi calibration values storage. maybe it is corrupted.

To test the watchdog hypothesis, add a yield() to the loop. According to this forum thread, this could be an issue (https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=85033).
